# Erlang curl and exclude various text/tags

Tags: curl, erlang

I am curling a webpage with erlang and naturally getting html code, so far so good!
This is how my code looks like:

```
startCURL()->
Cmd = "curl \"" ++ "http://mywebsite.com/something.html" ++ "\"",
Output = os:cmd(Cmd),
io:format("The HTML output: ~s~n", [Output]).
```

Now to the problem, I want to exclude various tags in the html via erlang. Example:
`<b>`Hello`</b>` to "Hello" without the `<b>` and `</b>`.

I really appreciate all help I can get! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the replace function in [re module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#replace-3) to replace unwanted tags with empty strings.

```
re:replace(Output, "</?br>", "", [global]).
```

Comment: Hello, thanks, I think we are close now. Unfortunately your code example doesn't replace anything. Not even pure text I had in a test html file.

Comment: It does work. You are probably printing Output again, that's why seeing no change. You should do Output2 = re:replace(Output, "</?br>", "", [global]).  and then print Output2. Variables are immutable in Erlang.

Comment: I was printing Output again, now with Output2 it works perfectly! Exactly how I wanted it, many thanks @cashmere!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Now when my replacing is working, how do I replace longer tags like <div class="content"> ?

Comment: And is it possible to make a filter that only shows content between for example <div class="content"> and <div class="footer"> when writing out with io:format? Thanks for all help so far!

Comment: As RobertoAloi pointed out, if you want to do more complicated stuff with html, you may want to not to use regexes and checkout the link in legoscia's answer. I just suggested an easy way to filter out some tags. You can basically filter anything out if you can write the regex for it.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](http://ppolv.wordpress.com/2008/05/09/fun-with-mochiwebs-html-parser-and-xpath/) shows how to use `mochiweb_html` to do various tricks with HTML documents.  Hope that's enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I am looking for.